# Get all available UIViewController identifiers of a UIStoryboard

Tags: swift

I am currently implementing some "Help Tours" for my app (you know, the kind of screens that can both be helpful and pretty annoying).
I want to implement this features as generically as possible. I have the following code:

```
extension UIStoryboard
{
    class func instantiate<T : UIViewController>(_ name: String) -> T?
    {
        let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: name, bundle: nil)
        let viewController = storyboard.instantiateInitialViewController() as? T

        return viewController
    }
}

class HelpTourService
{
    static func show(tour: HelpTour, with parent: UIViewController?, controller: Controller?)
    {
        guard let parentViewController = parent else { return }

        if let help: HelpTourViewController = UIStoryboard.instantiate("HelpTour")
        {
            help.controller = controller
            help.content = HelpTourContent(tour.storyboard, tour.identifiers)

            parentViewController.present(help, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
    }
}

enum HelpTour
{
    case basic
    case premium
    case dataScreens
    case copyFiles
    case fitness

    var storyboard: String
    {
        switch self
        {
        case .basic:
            return "FirstStartPages"
        case .premium:
            return "PremiumTour"
        case .dataScreens:
            return "DataScreensTour"
        case .copyFiles:
            return "CopyFilesTour"
        case .fitness:
            return "FitnessTour"
        }
    }

    var identifiers: [String]
    {
        switch self
        {
        case .basic:
            return ["welcome", "page1", "page2", "page3", "page4", "page5"]
        case .premium:
            return ["welcome", "page1", "page2", "page3", "page4", "page5", "page6"]
        case .dataScreens:
            return ["welcome", "page1", "page2", "page3"]
        case .copyFiles:
            return ["welcome", "page1", "page2"]
        case .fitness:
            return ["welcome"]
        }
    }
}
```

This allows me to open a tour from anywhere in my code:

```
HelpTourService.show(tour: .basic, with: self, controller: nil)
```

I would really like to remove the `identifiers` property. So I was wondering if it is possible to get all available identifiers of a `UIStoryboard` programatically (preferably using Swift and without any additional frameworks)?

Something like this:

```
if let storyboard = UIStoryboard.instantiate("Storyboard")
{
    for identifier in storyboard.identifiers
    {
        // Do something
    }
}
```

Comment: No, it isn't. Storyboards are not introspectable in that way. Knowing the identifiers is up to you.

Comment: Okay, sad to hear but good to know.

Comment: the only way to kinda do it is generate your enum on the fly at buildtime by inspecting storyboard... but that's ugly

Comment: You can add a pre-build script to parse storyboard and convert identifiers to an enum.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way of doing this programmatically, but

If it's just a matter of getting an updated list of all identifiers then your could do a search in all .storyboard files (they're readable xml) and compile a json with all the values by looking for

```
<viewController storyboardIdentifier=
```

You would have to do this as a pre compile script, since those identifier values are not available after compilation. 
The storyboard themselves get compiled and become unreadable at runtime. 
Also there is no API in UIStoryboard to access a list of identifiers.

You could then load the json file with the identifiers in your applications during application's startup.

I personally use enums to store the identifiers and it's been working fine for me.

Comment: Although I like the idea, I think it is way easier to simply update my `HelpTour` enum once in a while. I just hoped that there was a way to get the identifiers programatically, I did not know that the storyboard files get compiled and some information is lost.

Comment: yes, I do the same thing in my projects. identifiers don't get added that often anyway.